# How do I reference a webpack-packed file from my static HTML?

Tags: angular, webpack

In my Angular 5 project, my `index.html` shows a Loading message with a background image:

```
<html>
<head>
    <base href="/" />
    <style type="text/css">
#loadingIndicator {
    background-image: url('style/Loading.png');
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<root-component>
    <div id="loadingIndicator">
        <p>Loading...
    </div>
</root-component>
</body>
</html>
```

My `.angular-cli.json` file includes this image as an asset:

```
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    // ...
    "apps": [
        {
            "assets": [
                "assets",
                "favicon.ico",
                "style/Loading.png"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I also reference the `style/Loading.png` image in my main `style.css` for other Angular components.

When I perform an `ng build --prod` then my `dist` directory looks like this:

```
/index.html
/Loading.9af4172f5a20c0475770.png
/favicon.ico
/style/Loading.png
/styles.2g4fa4ee39253c42123b.bundle.css
/etc...
```

Notice how `Loading.png` is included twice: as `Loading.9af4172f5a20c0475770.png` and as `/style/Loading.png`.

Is there any way to get `ng build` or `webpack` to change my inline-CSS to reference the hashed filename of the asset so it doesn't include the file twice - and cause my users to download the file twice:

```
#loadingIndicator {
    background-image: url('Loading.9af4172f5a20c0475770.png');
}
```

Or could it at least inline the image entirely as a `data:` URI? (That would make sense for an Angular loading page, as the app might have loaded before the second HTTP request for the image completes).

I couldn't find any information online for `webpack` in general, nor Angular, but I found this page for Vue.js: https://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/static.html which only covers getting asset-paths from JavaScript, not having it rewrite static HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Its difficult to assist without seeing your Webpack config, but take a look at [HtmlWebpackPlugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin). By default, the plugin generates an HTML file from scratch with all necessary includes; however, you can configure it to load an HTML file as a template.